# How to create an Android EditText programatically without a border

Tags: android

I'm creating a table (TableLayout containing TableRows) of EditText fields programmatically.

However, when I do so I notice that there is a rather large border around each EditText field compared to (e.g.) a TextView with the same content.  How do I get rid of this border?

Things I have tried:

```
    text.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,null,null); // does nothing
    text.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0); // does nothing
    text.setBackgroundColor(0); // turns the cell black; since the text is already back this makes it impossible to see anything
```

For reference, the function creating the EditText looks like this:

```
public View TextField(String def){
    EditText text = new EditText(this);
    text.setText(def);
    text.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,null,null);
    text.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    //text.setBackgroundColor(0);
    return text;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

The first two rows are EditText fields; the last two are TextView fields.

Comment: "However, when I do so I notice that there is a rather large border around each EditText field" -- you may wish to post a screenshot illustrating what you mean by "border".

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Well, partly that's tied to theme, as you are seeing the original `Theme` as opposed to `Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Material`, etc. That is handled via the widget background, but that background is a `StateListDrawable`, not a simple color (and certainly not a simple black background).

Comment: @CommonsWare Is this the background for just the EditText field, or for the whole window, or what?   When you mention theme it sounds like you mean the latter, but then I don't understand why TextView fields have a different border than EditText?

Comment: "Is this the background for just the EditText field, or for the whole window, or what?" -- um, well, the white thingy outlined by the orange thingy is the background of the `EditText`. "but then I don't understand why TextView fields have a different border than EditText?" -- um, because while `EditText` extends `TextView`, it has a different default background, in all standard themes. That background is a `StateListDrawable`, to handle things like indicating focus (e.g., the orange thingy).